# keep getting error lnk 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a basic log in page but when I try to build the program, I get a syntax error.

Here is the error that I get:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct UserRecord __cdecl ReadData(class 
std::basic_ifstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,struct UserRecord)" (?ReadData@@YA?
AUUserRecord@@AAV?$basic_ifstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@U1@@Z) referenced in function _main  
c:\Users\Emerson\documents\visual studio 
2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication11\ConsoleApplication11\small_eas12d_p6.obj ConsoleApplication11
```

I get the same error twice for when the program calls the main function from what I can get. However I cannot figure out a way to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int Max_Persons = 50, Max_Attempts = 3;

struct UserRecord
{
   string userID;
   string password;
   int PIN;

};

typedef struct UserRecord AccountInfo;

void PrintHeading();
void Login_Success();
void Kicked();
void Login_Failed(int);
void FileCheck(ifstream &);
UserRecord ReadData(ifstream &, AccountInfo);
bool checkData(bool, AccountInfo, int);




int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    bool passorfail = false;
    int attempts = 0;

    ifstream infile;



    AccountInfo Accounts[Max_Persons];

    FileCheck(infile);

    Accounts[Max_Persons] = ReadData(infile, Accounts[Max_Persons]);

    PrintHeading();

    do
    {
        passorfail = checkData(passorfail, Accounts[Max_Persons], attempts);

    } while (!passorfail || attempts < 3);

    if (attempts <= 3)
        Kicked();

    if(passorfail)
        Login_Success();

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}

AccountInfo ReadData(ifstream & infile, AccountInfo Accounts[Max_Persons])
{
    int UserNum;
    string str;


    getline(infile, str, '\n' );

     UserNum = atoi(str.c_str());


    for(int i = 0; i < UserNum; i++)
    {
        infile >> Accounts[i].userID;

        infile >> Accounts[i].password;

        infile >> Accounts[i].PIN;

    }



    return Accounts[Max_Persons];
}



void FileCheck(ifstream & infile)
{
    string FileName;

    cout << "Filenames must not contain blanks ." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the file name to decode ->" << endl;
    cin >> FileName;


        infile.open(FileName.c_str());

        while(!infile)
        {

                FileName.clear();

                cout << "Sorry \"" << FileName << "\" is not a valid file name. Please try again." << endl;

                cin >> FileName;
                infile.open(FileName.c_str());
        }

        return;
}


bool checkData(bool passorfail, AccountInfo Accounts[Max_Persons], int attempts)
{

    string givenID;
    string givenPass;
    int givenPin;

    do
    {
        cout << "Login" << endl;
        cout << "UserID: ";
        cin >> givenID;
        cout << endl << "Password: ";
        cin >> givenPass;
        cout << endl << "Pin: ";
        cin >> givenPin;

        for(int i = 0; i < Max_Persons; i++)
        {
            if(givenID == Accounts[i].userID)
            {
                if (givenPass == Accounts[i].password)
                {
                    if (givenPin == Accounts[i].PIN)
                    {
                        passorfail = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(!passorfail)
            {
                Login_Failed(attempts);
                attempts++;
            }

    } while (!passorfail || attempts < 3);

    return passorfail;
}

void PrintHeading()
{
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "------         Welcome to MyGreatWebsite.com         ------\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "**Unauthorized access to this stie is strictly prohibited**";

    return;
}

void Login_Failed(int attempts)
{
    cout << "Sorry, that username and/or password was incorrect" << endl;
    cout << "You have used " << attempts << " of your attempts to login. " << endl;
    cout << "You only have 3 attempts total before you are automatically " << endl;
    cout << "kicked from the system" << endl; 

    return;
}

void Kicked()
{
    cout << "Sorry, you have reached the maximum number attempts " << endl;
    cout << "to access this site, please have a good day" << endl;

    return;
}

void Login_Success()
{
    cout << "Welcome to MyGeatWebsite.com" << endl;
    cout << "Enjoy your stay" << endl;

    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

LNK2019 isn't a "syntax error". it's a diagnostic issued by the linker. it means that some function that has been declared and used, in this case `ReadData`, has not been defined, or if defined, has not been compiled, or if compiled, has not been passed to the linker.

Your forward declaration of `ReadData` does not match the implementation.

A simple way to avoid that is to not use forward declaration. Forward declarations are in the language for a reason (supporting recursion, and supporting separate compilation), but as a general convention they have no advantage and do have some problems, including extra maintenance work and the problem that you have encountered now. Instead place each function definition before the point of first use.

Comment: Forward declarations should be present in most non-trivial production-quality programs with several compilation units. They're invaluable in reducing coupling (and tight coupling is usually an indication of a poor design) and also help with encapsulation. Support of recursion and separate compilation are secondary and are actually derivatives of the above.

Comment: @icepack: can you expand on how support for separate compilation is secondary and a derivative of using several compilation units.

Comment: I meant that *technically* the need for separate compilation is a derivative of the *design* decision to actually create several compilation units (although the main part of my comment is about loose coupling).

Comment: oh that makes sense (not)

Comment: Well, for anything serious I usually start with the design before throwing in a bunch of code. Maybe that's just me. Anyway, a "as a general convention they have no advantage" advice is a bad one, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, on Visual Studio errors that start with `LNK` are [Linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) erros.
Now for the cause of this error, it seems that you have declared the `ReadData` prototype as

```
UserRecord ReadData(ifstream &, AccountInfo);
```

while in the function definition it is:

```
AccountInfo ReadData(ifstream & infile, AccountInfo Accounts[Max_Persons]) { }
```

The linker probably assumes that there are two distinct function, one that receives a single `AccountInfo` and one that receives and array of `AccountInfo[]`. Change the prototype of `ReadData` to match the function definition and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Changed the prototype but I still get the same error

Comment: How did you change it? Your `main()` expects a function that takes one `AccountInfo`. So make sure you declare both function and prototype as `UserRecord ReadData(ifstream & file, AccountInfo account);` or change the function call on main and pass an array to it.